# In Angular js how to convert Date format

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime

```
 public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            Entities contextObj = new Entities();
            var employeeList = contextObj.CCFFares.ToList();
            //return Json(employeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return this.Json((from obj in contextObj.CCFFares
                              select new
                              {
                                  ID = obj.ID,
                                  Departure_Airport = obj.Departure_Airport,
                                  Destination = obj.Destination,
                                  Departure_Date = obj.Departure_Date.ToString(),
                                  Return_Date = obj.Return_Date.ToString(),
                                  Airline = obj.Airline,
                                  Fare = obj.Fare,
                                  Offer_Ends = obj.Offer_Ends,
                                  Ailine_Class = obj.Airline_Class
                              }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I got an issue where i need to show the date in dd/mm/yy but i am receiving in this manner 2/20/2017 12:00:00 AM what i really dint want to  and when i bind the value in view without to string conversion i do get the date time in this way "    /Date(1479600000000)/   "where i need to show the date in dd/mm/yy  simply can someone guide me on this please !

Comment: You can format the date using date filter

Answer (score 1):

While binding to your html view use date filter as follows

```
{{your date in milliseconds| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep .toString() as it is

Try by adding custom filter for date
Angular code

```
app.filter('filterDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) { 
 return function (input, format) {

     return (input) ? $filter('date')(input, format) : '';  
};
```

Your Html should be like

```
<li class="mark"> {{Departure_Date | filterDate : 'dd-MM-yy' }}</li>
```